# Serial no of i-phone/i-pod

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can anyone tell me the way for getting the UDID number of an iPhone  programmatically .I found some private framework like IOKit i dont want to use this.

Comment: Why do you need the serial number?

Comment: Huh. This question has been heavily edited since it was originally posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HI,

```
NSString *UDID=[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSLog(@"UDID==> %@",UDID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need it? Tell us what problem you're trying to solve and we may be able to help you find another way to solve it. For instance:

1. If you're trying to get a device-unique value, the UDID is precisely that.
2. If you're trying to tie your app's data to a specific device... the UDID is again the right thing for the job.
3. If you're trying to determine a model based on serial numbers, consider using `uname()` instead.
4. If you're trying to spy on the user... naughty you!

Can you give us more information on your situation?

Comment: What you think is best doesn't matter when what you think is best can't be done. ;)